# How to load all records that were already published from Kafka?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a pyspark structure streaming python app up set up like this

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("data streaming app")\
    .getOrCreate()


data_raw = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafkahost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "my_topic")\
    .load()

query = data_raw.writeStream\
    .outputMode("append")\
    .format("console")\
    .option("truncate", "false")\
    .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds")\
    .start()\
    .awaitTermination()
```

And All that shows up is this

```
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|key|value|topic|partition|offset|timestamp|timestampType|
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+---------+-------------+

19/03/04 22:00:50 INFO streaming.StreamExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "ab24bd30-6e2d-4c2a-92a2-ddad66906a5b",
  "runId" : "29592d76-892c-4b29-bcda-f4ef02aa1390",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2019-03-04T22:00:49.389Z",
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 852,
    "getBatch" : 180,
    "getOffset" : 135,
    "queryPlanning" : 107,
    "triggerExecution" : 1321,
    "walCommit" : 27
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaSource[Subscribe[my_topic]]",
    "startOffset" : null,
    "endOffset" : {
      "my_topic" : {
        "0" : 303
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ConsoleSink@74fad4a5"
  }
}
```

As you can see, `my_topic` has 303 messages there but I cant get it to show. Additional information includes that I am using the confluent Kafka JDBC connector to query an oracle database and store the rows into the kafka topic. I have an avro schema registry setup with that. If required, I will share these property files as well.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you check the logs of the broker and make sure there are no errors?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous, no need, I figured out what was the issue. It was my limited understanding on how streams worked... What i wanted to do is display the messages from the kafka topic since it first started as well as incoming messages. To do that, all I needed to do was an an extra option with the params `startingOffsets` and `earliest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a streaming application, this Spark Structure streaming only reads messages as soon as they are publish. What I wanted to do, for testing purposes was read everything in the topic. In order to do that, all you have to do is an an extra option in `readStream`, i.e. `option("startingOffsets", "earliest")`.

```
data_raw = spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafkahost:9092")\
    .option("subscribe", "my_topic")\
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()
```